# Piped log program failed unexpectedly when using sed with Apache at windows

Tags: apache, logging, sed, proxy

I am using sed to mask some data in proxy logs of Apache at windows.

Putting command in httpd.conf file is :

```
 CustomLog "|$'C:/Program Files (x86)/GnuWin32/bin/sed' -i 's/password=[^ ]*/password=masked/' 'logs/proxy-access.log'" combined
```

on starting Apache service command prompts start opening and closing and in error.logs found exception i.e :

```
AH00106: piped log program ''C:/Program Files (x86)/GnuWin32/bin/sed' -i 's/password=[^ ]*/password=masked/' 'C:/Apache24/logs/proxy-access.log'' failed unexpectedly
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution that we can apply: This is Apache only solution

we can remove parameters from only those requests which contains sensitive data like password.
Although such type of request should be POST but as these are in use then we can make their logging like POST in apache log files and hide sensitive data.

This can be achieved with Apache only configuration. Below is the script I have tested at local

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} password
RewriteRule ^ - [E=allowParamLogging:no]
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%m %U %H\" %>s %b" custom_format_without_queryString
LogFormat "%h \"%{BALANCER_WORKER_NAME}e\" %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" custom_format_with_queryString
CustomLog 'logs/proxy-access.log' custom_format_without_queryString expr=(reqenv('allowParamLogging')=='no')
CustomLog 'logs/proxy-access.log' custom_formate_with_queryString expr=!(reqenv('allowParamLogging')=='no')
```

We can set environment variable (i.e allowParamLogging) using rewrite rule for request if that request contains keywords like password.
Then on the basis of environment variable we can choose the different formats of logs like custom_format_with_queryString for logging query parameter and custom_format_without_queryString for hiding query parameters.

Here is the sample of request's log

which contains the password :

```
::1 - - [08/Nov/2018:16:15:00 +0530] "GET /api/documents/ HTTP/1.1" 204 -
```

which does not contains the password:

```
::1 "-" - [08/Nov/2018:16:15:03 +0530] "GET /api/documents/?type=invoice HTTP/1.1" 204 - "rbose" "curl/7.61.1"
```